# implementing trees after reading from a text file

Tags: c, tree

I want to implement/make a tree with the integer number after reading from a text file.

My tree implementation works fine, the code is almost good. but, there is a problem about reading the integers from text file (incuding numbers as 1 4 7 2 9 6 ).

```
main(){

   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen(tree.txt,"r");
```

in this above line, i open the file. and i get pointer fp to the first integer in the text file.

should i change * tree in the line below to apply tree implementation on the text file?

```
   void bitree_init(BiTree *tree, void (*destroy)(void *data)) {


   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Initialize the binary tree.                                               *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   tree->size = 0;
   tree->destroy = destroy;
   tree->root = NULL;

   return;

   }

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  ---------------------------- bitree_destroy ----------------------------  *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   void bitree_destroy(BiTree *tree) {

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Remove all the nodes from the tree.                                       *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   bitree_rem_left(tree, NULL);

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  No operations are allowed now, but clear the structure as a precaution.   *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   memset(tree, 0, sizeof(BiTree));

   return;

   }

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  ---------------------------- bitree_ins_left ---------------------------  *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   int bitree_ins_left(BiTree *tree, BiTreeNode *node, const void *data) {

   BiTreeNode         *new_node,
                      **position;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Determine where to insert the node.                                       *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if (node == NULL) {

      /**************************************************************************
      *                                                                         *
      *  Allow insertion at the root only in an empty tree.                     *
      *                                                                         *
      **************************************************************************/

      if (bitree_size(tree) > 0)
         return -1;

      position = &tree->root;

      }

   else {

      /**************************************************************************
      *                                                                         *
      *  Normally allow insertion only at the end of a branch.                  *
      *                                                                         *
      **************************************************************************/

      if (bitree_left(node) != NULL)
         return -1;

      position = &node->left;

   }

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Allocate storage for the node.                                            *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if ((new_node = (BiTreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(BiTreeNode))) == NULL)
      return -1;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Insert the node into the tree.                                            *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   new_node->data = (void *)data;
   new_node->left = NULL;
   new_node->right = NULL;
   *position = new_node;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Adjust the size of the tree to account for the inserted node.             *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   tree->size++;

   return 0;

   }

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  --------------------------- bitree_ins_right ---------------------------  *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   int bitree_ins_right(BiTree *tree, BiTreeNode *node, const void *data) {

   BiTreeNode         *new_node,
                      **position;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Determine where to insert the node.                                       *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if (node == NULL) {

      /**************************************************************************
      *                                                                         *
      *  Allow insertion at the root only in an empty tree.                     *
      *                                                                         *
      **************************************************************************/

      if (bitree_size(tree) > 0)
         return -1;

      position = &tree->root;

      }

   else {

      /**************************************************************************
      *                                                                         *
      *  Normally allow insertion only at the end of a branch.                  *
      *                                                                         *
      **************************************************************************/

      if (bitree_right(node) != NULL)
         return -1;

      position = &node->right;

   }

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Allocate storage for the node.                                            *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if ((new_node = (BiTreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(BiTreeNode))) == NULL)
      return -1;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Insert the node into the tree.                                            *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   new_node->data = (void *)data;
   new_node->left = NULL;
   new_node->right = NULL;
   *position = new_node;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Adjust the size of the tree to account for the inserted node.             *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   tree->size++;

   return 0;

   }

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  ---------------------------- bitree_rem_left ---------------------------  *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   void bitree_rem_left(BiTree *tree, BiTreeNode *node) {

   BiTreeNode         **position;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Do not allow removal from an empty tree.                                  *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if (bitree_size(tree) == 0)
      return;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Determine where to remove nodes.                                          *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if (node == NULL)
      position = &tree->root;
   else
      position = &node->left;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Remove the nodes.                                                         *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if (*position != NULL) {

      bitree_rem_left(tree, *position);
      bitree_rem_right(tree, *position);

      if (tree->destroy != NULL) {

         /***********************************************************************
         *                                                                      *
         *  Call a user-defined function to free dynamically allocated data.    *
         *                                                                      *
         ***********************************************************************/

         tree->destroy((*position)->data);

      }

      free(*position);
      *position = NULL;

      /**************************************************************************
      *                                                                         *
      *  Adjust the size of the tree to account for the removed node.           *
      *                                                                         *
      **************************************************************************/

      tree->size--;

   }

   return;

   }

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  --------------------------- bitree_rem_right ---------------------------  *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   void bitree_rem_right(BiTree *tree, BiTreeNode *node) {

   BiTreeNode         **position;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Do not allow removal from an empty tree.                                  *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if (bitree_size(tree) == 0)
      return;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Determine where to remove nodes.                                          *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if (node == NULL)
      position = &tree->root;
   else
      position = &node->right;

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Remove the nodes.                                                         *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if (*position != NULL) {

      bitree_rem_left(tree, *position);
      bitree_rem_right(tree, *position);

      if (tree->destroy != NULL) {

         /***********************************************************************
         *                                                                      *
         *  Call a user-defined function to free dynamically allocated data.    *
         *                                                                      *
         ***********************************************************************/

         tree->destroy((*position)->data);

      }

      free(*position);
      *position = NULL;

      /**************************************************************************
      *                                                                         *
      *  Adjust the size of the tree to account for the removed node.           *
      *                                                                         *
      **************************************************************************/

      tree->size--;

   }

   return;

   }

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  ----------------------------- bitree_merge -----------------------------  *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   int bitree_merge(BiTree *merge, BiTree *left, BiTree *right, const void
      *data) {

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Initialize the merged tree.                                               *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   bitree_init(merge, left->destroy);

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Insert the data for the root node of the merged tree.                     *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   if (bitree_ins_left(merge, NULL, data) != 0) {

      bitree_destroy(merge);
      return -1;

   }

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Merge the two binary trees into a single binary tree.                     *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   bitree_root(merge)->left = bitree_root(left);
   bitree_root(merge)->right = bitree_root(right);

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Adjust the size of the new binary tree.                                   *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   merge->size = merge->size + bitree_size(left) + bitree_size(right);

   /*****************************************************************************
   *                                                                            *
   *  Do not let the original trees access the merged nodes.                    *
   *                                                                            *
   *****************************************************************************/

   left->root = NULL;
   left->size = 0;
   right->root = NULL;
   right->size = 0;

   return 0;

   }
}
```

Comment: Note:  I took out all the comments and blank lines and found the code, as a whole, easier to understand.  Yet still do not see how code is used in `main()`.

Comment: what do you mean by 'how code is used in main() ?'

Comment: Code does `main(){ FILE *fp; fp = fopen(tree.txt,"r");` and then what?  It never uses the `bitree_` functions.

Comment: _My tree implementation works fine_ - how do you know?